# How to use location hash with ajax forms so clicking 'back' button returns user to the previous page state?

Tags: ajax, hash, location

I read the manual about location hash, but seems I didn't understand it.

I do like this:

```
$.ajax({
 url: "/tst.htm",
success: function(data){
     $("#center").html(data.content);
     location.hash="#ACHTUNG";
   }
});
```

and when I press 'back' in the browser, I return to the blank browser page, not to the page I created to test how location hash works.

I need a simple answer how to workaround this most common and simple ajax-based task, not please again a reference to the manual.